# Build de projeto Cordova já pronto

Tags: ios, apache-cordova

Pessoal estou tendo problemas estranhos ao fazer o build de um projeto cordova. Eu tenho pasta wwww no raiz do projeto e pasta www em platforms/iOS. Então, o projeto mesmo encontra-se nesta ultima. quando faço o build para a gerar a aplicação, ele executa o app a partir do www fora de platforms. O que eu poderia estar fazendo errado?

Comment: mas o correto é colocar fora dentro de platforms é gerado pelo cordova. qual o problema ?

Answer (score 0):

O conteúdo das pastas platforms é alterado a cada build; assim, o código principal tem que ficar na pasta www na raiz do projeto.